# How do I access scoped entries in a class method in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have an RSS Feed class, which holds the feed url, name, etc. and I want to add a `posts` method to loop through each post in the feed and returns the results. I have the following code, but am getting many `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` errors.

```
class Feed
  field :name
  field :url

  belongs_to :project

  def self.posts
    results = []
    scoped.all.each {|f| results << RssFeed.get(f.name, f.url)}
    results
  end
end
```

My application has different Projects, and each project has many feeds. So in my code I'm trying to get all posts from all rss feeds that belong to a particular project like this:

```
project.feeds.cached
```

I am able to call `scoped` in my posts method which will return a `Mongoid::Criteria` but `scoped.all.each` or `scoped.entries` both return stack level too deep errors. I was wondering how I can access the project.feeds scope from within my posts class method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My silly mistake - `cached` is a reserved word.